# R: Using character entries in a data frame to index row names and column names to extract elements from another data frame

Tags: r, loops, indexing, quote

I would like to use two columns within my data frame `transport_data` to extract corresponding values in another data frame `CI_elec`. The `scenario` and `year` columns in `transport_data` give the row name and column name that should be used to select data from `CI_elec` in the `CI_pkm` function.

The head of `transport_data` has the following format:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 9
  scenario type  year  occupancy passenger.km vehicle.km TWh.vehicle.km
  <chr>    <chr> <chr>     <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>          <dbl>
1 iea6     walk~ 2011          1      2.70e12    2.70e12              0
2 iea6     walk~ 2015          1      3.05e12    3.05e12              0
3 iea6     walk~ 2020          1      3.38e12    3.38e12              0
4 iea6     walk~ 2025          1      3.53e12    3.53e12              0
5 iea6     walk~ 2030          1      3.57e12    3.57e12              0
6 iea6     walk~ 2035          1      3.47e12    3.47e12              0
```

`CI_elec` looks like this, where iea6 to rcp2 are the row names and 2011 to 2050 are the column names:

```
             2011         2015         2020         2025         2030
iea6 0.0005787902 0.0005118950 0.0005047792 0.0005075581 0.0005060511
iea4 0.0005787902 0.0005118950 0.0004890350 0.0004754852 0.0004484639
iea2 0.0005787902 0.0005118095 0.0004521967 0.0003997270 0.0003085964
rcp8 0.0005787902 0.0005107324 0.0005350430 0.0005468413 0.0005447299
rcp6 0.0005787902 0.0005114301 0.0005086695 0.0005147240 0.0005129202
rcp2 0.0005787902 0.0005118596 0.0004671089 0.0004361393 0.0003887369
             2035         2040         2045         2050
iea6 0.0004944316 0.0004812976 4.485943e-04 4.238010e-04
iea4 0.0004220578 0.0003909761 3.383678e-04 3.012483e-04
iea2 0.0002386181 0.0001679809 7.607596e-05 1.208776e-05
rcp8 0.0005370120 0.0005221591 4.914019e-04 4.727123e-04
rcp6 0.0004935201 0.0004928346 4.420779e-04 3.983801e-04
rcp2 0.0003437802 0.0003163802 2.963748e-04 2.790785e-04
```

The function `CI_pkm` is:

```
    
    for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
    
    if (grepl('fuel|liquid', data[i, 2])) {
      CI[i] <- (data[i, 7] * CI_fuels$liquid) / data[i, 4]
    } else if (grepl('gas', data[i, 2])) {
      CI[i] <- (data[i, 7] * CI_fuels$gas) / data[i, 4]
    } else if (grepl('elec|EV', data[i, 2])) {
      CI[i] <- (data[i, 7] * CI_elec[data[i, 1], data[i, 3]]) / data[i, 4]
    }
    }
    as.numeric(CI)
  }
```

`CI_pkm` does not run because the values passed to `CI_elec` are not quoted and so they cannot be used to extract data from `CI_elec`. What I would like to do is extract data from `CI_elec` using the values held in the `scenario` column of `transport_data` (for the row name) and the `year` column (for the column name).

My first thought is that I need to add quotation marks to the values in the `scenario` and `year` column (perhaps using `dQuote` or similar); however, I was unable to get this to work. I was hoping that someone might have a good solution for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make `CI_elec` a `matrix`, you can use a matrix of row and column names to index it:

```
CI_elec_mat = as.matrix(CI_elec)
transport_data$new_column = CI_elec[cbind(transport_data$scenario, transport_data$year)]
```

The other nice solution I see would be to pivot `CI_elec` into a long form and use a join to add the column to `CI`.

Comment: Hi Gregor. Thanks for responding. I am struggling to get my head around your answer. I did not specify anything as `CI` in my code? What is this referring to?

Comment: Sorry - don't know where that come from. It should be `transport_data`.

Comment: That's great. Thanks. Could you briefly describe to me how this line of code works? It looks like a join based on `scenario` and `year`, but how did `cbind` know to join based on the values in these columns?

Comment: `cbind()` creates a matrix. `index = cbind(c(1, 3, 2), c(2, 2, 1)` creates a 2-dimensional matrix named `index`  with rows `1, 2`; `3, 2`; `2, 1`. We can interpret these as coordinate indices of another matrix of the form `(row, column)`, that is `(1st row, 2nd column), (3rd row, 2nd column), (2nd row, 1st column)`. We can use this 2d matrix of row/column indexes to subset another matrix `m`. `m[index]` will extract the values from those `(row, column)` coordinates. You can use either row/column numbers or row/column names. In this answer, we use row/column names.

Comment: Gregor, thank you! Your wisdom is much appreciated. Thanks for taking the time out to provide such a useful response.